# Possible DES keys

Tags: des

I have two questions.

1. How many DES-keys will produce the same first 32 bit ciphertext from the same plaintext?

Example:

Plaintext = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (hex)

Ciphertext = 01 02 03 04 ?? ?? ?? ?? (hex)

How many keys can produce this?

2. If I get another plaintext-ciphertext pair, where I know the entire plaintext, but only the first half of the ciphertext. How many keys can produce the same first half of a ciphertext?

Answer (score 0):

> How many DES-keys will produce the same first 32 bit ciphertext from the same plaintext?

Since a block cipher is modeled as a pseudo-random permutation, the answer is 2<sup>32</sup>.

> If I get another plaintext-ciphertext pair, where I know the entire plaintext, but only the first half of the ciphertext. How many keys can produce the same first half of a ciphertext?

If the plaintext is longer than a block, then this depends on the mode of operation you're using and the specific length.

If the plaintext is exactly one block and no padding is used, then it is the same answer as to your first question, because half a block are 32 bits for DES.